# Как собрать проект react js в режиме разработчика

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

Есть проект, в котором есть отправка на почту, из-за чего папка проекта выглядит следующим образом: в папке client расположена основная часть проекта, а index.js отвечает за отправку на почту[image]

В папке client расположена основная часть
[image]

локальный сервер разворачивается через команду npm run dev, когда я нахожусь в  папке проекта(не client, а именно всего проекта). Так вот вопрос: как мне выпустить проект(npm run build), чтобы сохранился весь функционал. Когда я пытаюсь его собрать, он ругается, что нет папки public, в которой находится index.html, папка эта находится в client. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может быть можно как-то public вынуть из клиента или наоборот все в клиент засунуть. Я по всякому пробовал, не получается

Comment: Из любопытства, а зачем вы именно так сделали? По описанию какое-то решение странное и не логичное

Comment: Я сам не в восторге. Очень много возился с отправкой на почту, и это единственный вариант, который заработал